# Front controller reached 100 router match iterations and routing issue

Tags: error, magento2.4, routing

Every day we get 100 if not 1000's of main.CRITICAL: Front controller reached 100 router match iterations error in our log. var/report is full of logs. Yesterday we had 280 logs in /report.

in var/report we get:

```
{"0":"Front controller reached 100 router match iterations","1":"#1
```

If I understand this correctly "1" is store id 1, but we do not have store id 1. It was moved to another server in 2019. The other weird thing is that the URL it complains about is quite strange. will try and explain it.

```
Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub\/index.php:29]\n","url":"\/se-utvalget\/action-town\/cobi_maserati-top_gun_maveric-cobi_world_of_tanks-armed_forces-hurtigruten-super_wings.html","script_name":"\/pub\/index.php","report_id":"00bfe14a862c933795bc361f3ae0771a40e30e947910d7e94900254a045cf5fd"}
```

Will break down the URL:
"se-utvalg" is the parent category
"Action Town" used to be a child category, but this was renamed a while ago. so should not be part of the URL.
"cobi_maserati" is a different child category. so don't know why it is here.
"top-gun" is also a different child category. nothing to do with the above categories.
and the same with the rest of the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URLs logged are mostly URLs crawled by bots and match the URL generated by the layered navigation for the filters.
All filters are configured to create links that can be followed by bots, and bots are following them creating any kind of URLs (working or not)...

All I needed to do was to configure the ES to set as NO FOLLOW, NO INDEX and the bots will stop following these.